# QPixmap / QImage alpha reduction with minimum ensured alpha

Tags: c++, performance, qt, qpixmap

I want to implement a method which reduces the alpha of every pixel in a QPixmap (4.8) by 1, every time it is called. In between calls new lines might be added to the image (with alpha of 255). Additionally I'd like to have a lower alpha threshold of say 15. Pixels which have initial alpha of 0 will keep that alpha. In pseudo-code:

```
if alpha == 0:
  newAlpha = 0
else:
  newAlpha = max(15, alpha - 1)
```

Right now I have two methods in mind. The first one is conversion to QImage and pixel-by-pixel reduction of alpha. However, this has two drawbacks: Performance and color artefacts: some pixels' colors change wildly. The artefacts appear when QPainting the resulting qpixmap onto another qpixmap filled with one color (with `QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceOver`). This is likely due to the dithering ?! I tried the two available ones, both produce these types artefacts.

```
QImage image = pixmap.toImage();
for (int y = 0; y < image.height(); ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < image.width(); ++x) {
        QRgb col = image.pixel(x,y);
        int alpha = qAlpha(col);

        if(alpha>15) {
            alpha -= 1;
            QRgb newCol = qRgba(qRed(col), qGreen(col), qBlue(col), alpha);
            image.setPixel(x,y, newCol);
        }
    }
}
pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(image, Qt::DiffuseAlphaDither | Qt::NoOpaqueDetection);
```

The artefacts appear with this:

```
QPixmap screen;
...
screen.fill(Qt::transparent);
QPainter painter( &screen );
// remove anti-aliasing, which (with current composition mode) results in even stronger artefacts
painter.setRenderHints(0); 
background.fill(someRandomColor);

painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, w, h, background);
painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, w, h, pixmap);
painter.end();
```

Alternatively I tried to map the above pseudo-code with QPixmap drawing operations. For instance, the composition mode of QPainter `QPainter::CompositionMode_DestinationIn` is useful to reduce the alpha. But I don't know how to handle the thresholding with simultaneous keeping the 0 alpha values.

So now there are actually three questions:

Can I avoid the color artefacts with the QImage detour ?

Or can I map the above pseude-code to pure QPixmap/QPainter operations ?

Is there a totally different idea to this ?

EDIT:

```
QImage image = pixmap.toImage().convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32);
```

Does seem to remove the artefacts. Before it would have converted to `QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied` and hence the artefacts. But now it is even less performant

Comment: Had the same issue today, the proposed in the edit solution did work perfectly, +1

Comment: I'm having a similar issue and believe `convertToFormat` is losing (a bit of) data in the process